# duplicate records in mysql with unique key enabled

Tags: mysql, innodb, load-data-infile

I have an InnoDB table with primary key and secondary unique key enabled. I used load data infile to dump a super big csv file (200m records). Then I found there are duplicated records in the table. It just doesn't make any sense to me. I wonder in what possible way this can happen? I checked the unique_checks is "ON" on both session and global.

The load data infile query I used:

```
load data infile "/tmp/test" replace into table temp.test fields terminated by ';' lines terminated by '\t\n' (first_name, last_name, birth_date, doc_number);
```

The table schema is:

```
create table test(
  id int(10) not null auto_increment,
  first_name varchar(30) not null default '',
  last_name varchar(30) not null default '',
  birth_date datetime null default null,
  doc_number int(10) not null default '',
  primary key (id, first_name),
  unique key (first_name, last_name, birth_date, doc_number),
  partition by range(id)
  PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (100,000,000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (400,000,000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (700,000,000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (maxvalue) ENGINE = InnoDB
)
```

The duplicate records I found:

```
select * from temp.test where first_name = 'John' and last_name = 'Doe';
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id ++ first_name ++ last_name ++        birth_date       ++ doc_number +
+ 3  ++    John    ++    Doe    ++   1967-05-04 00:00:00   ++    1843    +
+ 97 ++    John    ++    Doe    ++   1967-05-04 00:00:00   ++    1843    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I tried to reproduce this issue with a smaller dataset but it didn't work. So I'm trying to reproduce it on the origional dataset now. But it doesn't make sense to me cause I have the unique key on the table. So going further, any suggestion or direction on where to look at would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Did you by any chance turn off [`UNIQUE_CHECKS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_unique_checks) when doing the `LOAD DATA` command? If you copied and pasted from the Internet, many examples include this. It speeds up the process, but you can get duplicates.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't. Because it's a python script I used to do the load data infile. I didn't set unique_checks in the script. And also I use the same script to load data after this issue, it can always check on unique keys.